# Consulta select da resultado diferente en Vista que en Tabla aún con los mismos datos

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una vista y una tabla con exactamente los mismos datos cada una. Hice una consulta select a cada tabla y los resultados que obtengo difieren, lo cual es extraño ya que son idénticas en cuanto a contenido. Nunca se me había presentado algo así.

La columna saldo se calcula a partir de los valores de la columna Monto y dichos valores se suman si la columna Num tiene un 1 o se resta si tiene un 2. Va haciendo el cálculo agrupado por ID.

Select de tabla vista:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vista A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Num = 2 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * MontoUsar) SALDO
             FROM Vista
             WHERE IDCTA = A.IDCTA
             AND INDICE <= A.INDICE) B;
```

Resultado:  --> De acuerdo a los valores, donde se señala un 200 debería ir un cero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Select de Tabla:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Tabla A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN NUM = 2 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * MONTO) SALDO
             FROM dbo.Tabla
             WHERE ID = A.ID
             AND INDICE <= A.INDICE) B;
```

Resultado:  --> Columna Saldo se calcula correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando SQL Server 2008 r2.

Comment: Sería bueno que agregaras el código de la vista

Comment: Al parecer la forma de procesar la vista es diferente de la de un Store Procedure. Te recomendaría usar el SP para tu View  revisa este [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12739/whats-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-temp-table-in-sql-server-that-can-hold-the-re)

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código de la vista por favor? en una de las consultas usas Monto y en otra MontoUsar, solo quiero asegurarme que sea lo mismo

Comment: Agradezco sus comentarios. Ya logré resolverlo, lo único que hice fue que en la vista cambié la forma en que está enumerado el índice, es decir, en lugar de que sea consecutivo de forma general, ahora es consecutivo agrupado por ID. Con eso ya obtuve el resultado deseado. Los tipos de datos son los mismos tanto en la tabla como en la vista, por ello sigue pareciéndome extraño el comportamiento.